# ¿Puede alguien explicar este resultado de rendimiento?

Tags: javascript, revisión-de-código, rendimiento

Tengo los siguientes snippets en JavaScript:

**Script 1: múltiples `return`**

```
function prueba(valor) {
  if (valor == 1) {
    return '1';
  } else if (valor == 2) {
    return '2';
  } else if (valor == 3) {
    return '3';
  }
  return '';
}
prueba(3);
```

**Script 2: un único `return`**

```
function prueba(valor) {
  var devolucion = '';
  if (valor == 1) {
    devolucion = '1';
  } else if (valor == 2) {
    devolucion = '2';
  } else if (valor == 3) {
    devolucion = '3';
  }
  return devolucion;
}
prueba(3);
```

Realizo una [prueba de rendimiento](https://jsperf.com/soes-103909) y me aparece que el script con un `return` único es más rápido que el script con múltiples `return`, como se puede ver en esta imagen:

[image: Resultados test de rendimiento]

¿Por qué ocurre eso? ¿Puede alguien explicar este resultado de rendimiento?

Comment: Sin entrar en detalles de si la pregunta debe o no debe estar en [es.so], te diré que deberías añadir el código así como la información de los tiempos de ejecución como texto, si el servidor donde está alojada la imagen deja de funcionar, la pregunta no tendría sentido alguno. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] y leer la sección sobre [ask]. Bienvenido.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes? ¿Qué resultado esperabas? Debes añadir más información a la pregunta. Como te recomendaba Muriano, te diría que leas [ask] en el centro de ayuda, donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas. No termina de quedar claro lo que quieres, y si corres las pruebas varias veces, verás que [el resultado no siempre coincide](https://jsperf.com/soes-103909)

Answer (score 0):

Una posible explicación puede ser cómo se comporta internamente *Javascript* al hacer un `return`.

En primer lugar, en el **Script 2** al realizar un return sobre un literal (es decir, el numero que devuelves) internamente se debe reservar memoria para crear una variable temporal que referencia el literal, una vez utilizado la variable temporal deberá desecharse.

Por otra parte, si nos fijamos en el código del **Script 1** que utiliza la variable devolución, esta variable está declarada como `var devolución`  lo que *Javascript* interpretará como una variable global, es decir, la memoria se reservará una sola vez y en el `return` solo se pasará una referencia a la zona de memoria reservada. Esta zona de memoria, al contrario que con el primer caso comentado, no deberá destruirse una vez utilizado, ya que no es una variable temporal.